# combination multiple animation effect into one

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, jquery-animate

I would like to create a reveal text effect by using pure css and have following code. however I only want the effect to only apply on text area not the backdrop. if I change the `width` on `.reveal-block` to `80%` the backdrop just display right away before revealing all text done. but what I want to reveal the text with animation and once the text is done. display the backdrop right away. I have tried to use `animation-timing-function: linear, steps(1, end)` but the backdrop area still reveal in linear way

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.reveal {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.reveal-text {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.backdrop {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  visibility: visible;
}

.reveal-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  animation: reveal 10s linear 0.1s infinite;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="page-title reveal">
    <div class="reveal-block"></div>
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="reveal-text">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <span>test input<input></input></span>
      <span>test input<input></input></span>
      <span>test input<input></input></span>
      <span>test input<input></input></span>
      <span>test input<input></input></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I can see the text being revealed over 10seconds but the animation is set to infinite so the text gets covered again, the backdrop would only be revealed for a flash. Could you explain a bit more what it should look like?

Comment: I would to like to keep the effect on text and the effect doesn't apply on  backdrop and only display once all text is revealed

Comment: So you want the text to be revealed (gradually, with animation), the backdrop to then be shown (without animation) and then everything stay like that - not to animate continuously. Is that right?

Comment: @AHaworth yes. i know I can change `infinite` to `forwards` to stay the results

Comment: infinite and forwards are two different types of value - infinite probably you want to become 1, so it runs once only and forwards says to keep the last value of the animation when it ends.

Comment: @AHaworth understand, but what I am more confused is how to `revealed (gradually, with animation), the backdrop to then be shown (without animation)`